# Проверка пересечения объектов в определенный момент Unity

Tags: unity3d

Существуют несколько 3d объектов, в определенный момент необходимо проверить, пересекаются ли они. Ключевое - "в определенный момент". Он не зависит от момента их столкновения, так что OnCollisionEnter я использовать не могу. Есть ли действие-проверка пересечения?
Наверное, глупый вопрос, но найти по нему ничего не смог.

Comment: Уточните `Определённый момент`. Что должен случится в этот момент? Что программа должна сделать в этот момент.

Comment: определенный момент - условие? накопленные очки, подобранные предметы, еще что-то. объясните конкретней

Comment: Извините, я довольно безграмотно составил вопрос.
"Определенный момент" в данном контексте - событие, которое должно вызвать проверку на коллизию. Его суть не важна, но он привязан к апдейту скрипта.

Comment: Проблема в том, что объекты "ударяются" друг в друга? Поставьте у них коллайдеров свойство `IsTrigger` в `true` и проверяйте на столкновение триггеров.

Comment: Если же вам нужна коллизия, то возможно у вас отсутствует `RigidBody` или `SomeCollider` на объектах.

Answer (score 0):

OnCollisionEnter, if collission.CompareTag("имя  объекта") ....